# Filtering database results with 3 textBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I am writing a program in which the user can filter results from a database by 3 textboxes, however, the results are not being filtered correctly, because if one box is left empty, it doesn't display anything

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SQLiteConnection(cs);
    con.Open();

 if ((textBox2.Text==""||textBox.Text3=="")&&textBox1.Text!="")
    {
        adapt = new SQLiteAdapter("select data1, data2 from DataTable where data1 like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.Source = dt;
    }
    else if(textBox1.Text !="")
    {
        adapt = new SQLiteAdapter("select data1, data2 from DataTable where data1 like '" + textBox1.Text + "%' and data2 like '" + textBox2.Text + "%' and substr(data2,-2) like '" + textBox3.Text +"'", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.Source = dt;

    }
con.close();
}
```

That is the code that I am using on one of the textboxes, for the other two it look almost the same, except I change the if clause conditions.
Do I have to write 9 different clauses for each textbox, so that I cover all the options? Is there a right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would parameterize the query to prevent sql injection and use the `IFNULL` function to help you. This way you have one query to cover all scenarios. If any textbox is empty, the LIKE clause for that item will basically not filter anything out:

```
string qry = @"SELECT 
    data1, 
    data2 
FROM DataTable 
WHERE 
    data1 LIKE IFNULL(@data1, data1) AND 
    data2 LIKE IFNULL(@data2, data2) AND
    SUBSTR(data2, -2) LIKE IFNULL(@data3, data3)";
```

To create the parameters get the textbox values, set the parameter value to null if the textbox is empty. Do this for all 3 textboxes:

```
string data1 = null;
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text))
{
    data1 = textbox1.Text + "%";
}

SqlLiteCommand cmd = new SqlLiteCommand(qry, con);
SqlLiteParameter parData1 = new SqlLiteParameter("@data1", (object)data1 ?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.Add(parData1);
```

Now you can execute that command.

Comment: How exactly do I use that in my code? If I use that as `adapt = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);` I  get a Fill: SelectCommand.Connection exception on `adapt.Fill(dt);`.  I am relatively new to both sqlite and winforms.

Comment: See edit, I neglected to set the Connection. I'm writing this without testing it, you may have to fill in some syntax errors on your own. The point is, proper use of `IFNULL` can allow  you to use one query for any number of filters.

Comment: I get an unkmown error/insufficient parameters supplied to the command exception, and I don't have enough knowledge to know what exaclty is wrong.

Comment: See new edit. I don't use SQLite so I don't know if this works with that provider, but it may be that you need to pass `DBNull.Value` instead of `null` as the parameter value. Does it work if all three parameters have a value?

Answer (score 0):

In the Constructor or Form_Load wire up the TextBoxes change events to the one handler:

```
textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
textBox2.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
textBox3.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
```

And build up the WHERE clause dynamically instead of 9 conditions:

```
con = new SQLiteConnection(cs); 
con.Open();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("select * from DataTable where "); 
foreach (Control c in this.Controls) { 
TextBox t = c as TextBox; 
 if (t != null) { 
  if (t.Length > 0) {
  //In design-time set the TextBox Tag property to the SQL column name
  sb.Append(t.Tag.ToString() + " like '" + t.Text + "%' and ");
   }
  }
 }

string SQL = sb.ToString();
if (SQL.Length > 0) {
   SQL = SQL.Substring(0, SQL.Length-5);
}


adapt = new SQLiteAdapter(SQL, con); 
dt = new DataTable(); 
adapt.Fill(dt); 
dataGridView1.Source = dt;
```

You should also use a Stored Procedure or pay
Parameterized commands.

Comment: There' three textboxes, and I want the data to change independent from which textbox the filter is entered. So, do I need to use `textBox2.TextChanged += textBox3_TextChanged;`? And so on? Also, do I put the code you wrote in each separate textbox ? Note that I have no idea what stored procedure and parametrized commands are.